# spring-data-jpa SpEL in countQuery, using #{#entityName} - unexpected char: '#'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Updates since question where asked**

Issue was fixed by that PR:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/283

**Description**

I'm have configured spring-boot + spring-data-jpa project. And my repository has next custom query:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {
  ...
  @Query(
      value = " SELECT me.name FROM #{#entityName} me ",
      countQuery = " SELECT COUNT(me.name) FROM MyEntity me "
  )
  Page<String> findAllMyEntityNames(final Predicate predicate, final Pageable pageable);
  ...
}
```

and this is working fine. But obviuos for me would be better to use `#{#entityName}` everywhere - in query and in countQuery, ie:

```
countQuery = " SELECT COUNT(me.name) FROM #{#entityName} me "
```

So, my questions:

- what the difference with countQuery?
- why we can't use same SpEL here too?
- Question to spring team: is it posible in future add that functionality?

ps: if I'm using `#{#entityName}` inside countQuery, next exception occurs:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' [ SELECT COUNT(me.name) FROM #{#entityName} me ]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' [ SELECT COUNT(me.name) FROM #{#entityName} me ]
...
```

Thanks

---

Regards,
Maksim

Comment: In the shown case you can don't use `countQuery` at all...

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible test case, consider creating an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA/

Comment: @Cepr0, why? As far I'm getting page, I have to provide countQuery

Comment: @JensSchauder, I can provide an example which can easilly help to reproduce described issue. github repo is here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-spel-example also I've created JIRA here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1163

Comment: 'As far I'm getting page, I have to provide countQuery' - Spring constructs count query by itself for JPQL query. Creating custom `countQuery` is necessary for native query or for complex JPQL queries, with grouping, for example...

Comment: 'Spring constructs count query by itself for JPQL query', good to know, thanks. but what if i need provide custom query with some grouping like you said. it's strange I can't use same SpEL here too

Comment: repo with example for reproduce was moved here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-data-examples/blob/51d3dbf38703b2f74113608d5d2fa5d41750fd19/spel/app/src/main/java/daggerok/domain/MyEntityRepository.java#L15

Comment: bug was fixed: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1163 
proves here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-5-examples/blob/dd7e4e88d260acdc02cb4dd7de568aa9a533d4d9/spring-data-count-query-fix/src/main/java/daggerok/data/OrderRepository.java#L23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug was fixed by spring team: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1163

proves located here: https://github.com/daggerok/spring-5-examples/blob/dd7e4e88d260acdc02cb4dd7de568aa9a533d4d9/spring-data-count-query-fix/src/main/java/daggerok/data/OrderRepository.java#L23